# How to Edit JMX Config File so that Kafka Exposes A Topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, jmx-exporter

I have a Kafka server with a myTopic inside; myTopic is populated with plenty of data.

But when I inspect what metrics the Kafka server is allowing to be scraped, I don't see anything from myTopic.  This makes me think that although Kafka is running and myTopic is populating, myTopic isn't available for an outside server to scrape.  I need my JMX agent to include myTopic in the data it exposes to the other servers downstream in my pipeline.

I assembled my Kafka server using [this tutorial](https://www.robustperception.io/monitoring-kafka-in-a-docker-container-using-prometheus).

In this tutorial, you start up Kafka as a background process:

```
KAFKA_OPTS="$KAFKA_OPTS -javaagent:/home/me/kafka_2.11-2.1.1/jmx_prometheus_javaagent-0.6.jar=7071:/home/me/kafka_2.11-2.1.1/kafka-0-8-2.yml" \
  ./bin/kafka-server-start.sh config/server.properties &
```

The complete “kafka-0-8-2.yml” configuration file is included below.  I’m pretty convinced that myTopic is not “scrapable” from Kafka/JMX because it is not included as a rule in this file.  I’ve read the JMX config file README ([here](https://github.com/prometheus/jmx_exporter/blob/master/README.md)), and still don’t understand how to edit it.  When I try to edit an existing rule, Kafka crashes when I launch it.  Can anyone suggest an edit?  Many thanks.

Here’s the full “kafka-0-8-2.yml” file:

```
lowercaseOutputName: true
rules:
- pattern : kafka.cluster<type=(.+), name=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_cluster_$1_$2
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
    partition: "$4"
- pattern : kafka.log<type=Log, name=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_log_$1
  labels:
    topic: "$2"
    partition: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.controller<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_controller_$1_$2
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>Value
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec, request=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2_total
  labels:
    request: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(\w+), networkProcessor=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
  labels:
    request: "$3"
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(\w+), request=(\w+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
  labels:
    request: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.network<type=(.+), name=(\w+)><>Count
  name: kafka_network_$1_$2
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2_total
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*><>Count
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2_total
  type: COUNTER

- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.*)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
    topic: "$4"
    partition: "$5"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), topic=(.+), partition=(.*)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
    partition: "$4"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), topic=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    topic: "$3"
  type: COUNTER

- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+), brokerHost=(.+), brokerPort=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
    broker: "$4:$5"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+), clientId=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2
  labels:
    clientId: "$3"
- pattern : kafka.server<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_server_$1_$2

- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  labels:
    topic: "$4"
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)PerSec\w*, topic=(.+), partition=(.+)><>Count
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_total
  labels:
    topic: "$4"
    partition: "$5"
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_$4
  type: COUNTER
- pattern : kafka.(\w+)<type=(.+), name=(.+), (\w+)=(.+)><>(Count|Value)
  name: kafka_$1_$2_$3_$6
  labels:
    "$4": "$5"
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I need my JMX agent to include myTopic in the data it exposes to the other servers downstream in my pipeline."

Comment: @MickaelMaison  Sorry, Michael.  I've edited the post, see 2nd paragraph.  Basically, when I run JMX on my Kafka, I don't see the myTopic data in Kafka's exposed metrics.